# Measurability of a limit "in measure" of a sequence of measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sequence-of-function

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $\left(f_n\right)$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space $\left( X, \mathcal{A}, \mu \right)$, and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu\left( \{ x \in X : \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert \geq \varepsilon \} \right) = 0,$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Prove that $f$ is measurable. I tried to imitate the proof that pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable, but got stuck because I can only guarantee "convergence" on a set whose complement has arbitrarily small measure (but is not a null set). Any hints?

Comment: That's a strange exercise. Usually when convergence in measure is defined, the limit function is assumed to be measurable from the beginning. Otherwise, how can you be sure that $\mu(|f_n-f|\geq\epsilon)$ is even defined?

Comment: Exactly what I thought! I don't even know what is the point of the exercise, really...